# Css doesn't work in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am re-enacting google's 404 page with Jquery, but the Css isn't working. Why?

```
$("html").html("
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name=viewport content='initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width'>
<title>Error 404 (Not Allowed)!!</title>
<style>*{margin:0;padding:0}
html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}
html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}
body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}
* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}
p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}
ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}
a img{border:0}
@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}
#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}
@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}
#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
</style>
<a href=//www.google.com/>
<span id=logo aria-label=Google>
</span>
</a>
<p>
<b>404.</b>
<ins>That’s an error.</ins>
<p>The requested URL <code>/404</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
<form method='get' action='http://www.google.com/search'>
 <input placeholder='google 404 edition ' type='text' name='q' size='31' maxlength='Infinity' value='' />
 <input type='submit' value='Search' />
</form>
");
```

Comment: For the love of god, please format that code O.O

Comment: It's single line. I can't.

Comment: ["When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as <html>, <title>, or <head> elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed."](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

Comment: Note that you are attempting to insert `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>` WITHIN (as a child of) the `html` tag (`$("html").html("`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not create or add to your styles inside the style tags once the dom has been rendered

To confirm, try appending a style to the `style` tag in an html document

```
$('style').append('html {background:red;}')
```

Comment: You **can**, but not that way.

Comment: When i said that, I meant in the way of adding to or setting the contents of your style tag

Comment: Well, I guess css works, but not all of it.